# Multithreading in kernel model - LINUX

Tags: linux, multithreading, unix, operating-system, kernel

I have a question regarding the multithreading in the kernel module. Is it possible for the process to end before its main thread ended? And if it's possible for other threads to exist after the main thread has ended?

Comment: No, yes........

Comment: @MartinJames Hi, can you please elaborate? Thanks!